# C#/VB struct – how to avoid case with zero default values, which is considered invalid for given structure?

Tags: c#, .net, data-structures, vb.net, rules-and-constraints

How to implement some constrained .NET struct/structure (let's say `LimitedString`), where its state with default values (set by CLR to technical defaults, i.e. nulls, zeros, etc.) should be prohibited due to some design constraint?

For example in case of trivial `struct LimitedString`, properties are `String Value` and `int MaxLength = 10`, where value of the `MaxLength` property must be at least `1`. Value `0` is not allowed by design. But when I initalize the structure, I have `0` there. How to force value `10` into defaults?

I see two options:

1. Throw exception in `static` ([vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net) `shared`) parameterless constructor → force using only costructor(s) with parameters. *Impractical, parameterless use is expected sometimes.*
2. Add helper private field `IsInitialized` and while it is `false`, assume default values, i.e. `MaxLength = 10`. *Slightly higher complexity inside the struct.*

Is option #2 a legitimate way or does this violate some design principles?
Is there some better way than option #2?

---

EDIT: option #1 won't work anyway, mentioned constructor is called every time, even if other constructors are called.

Comment: Let 0 express 10 :) Then make property MaxLength { get { return 10 - maxLength} }; Also add similar transform in ctor. [whoops, I see there is already answer same like my comment]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unless you have a really, *really* good reason that this *has* to remain a Struct, I would recommend that you convert it to a Class.
That way, initialisation is completely under your control, through the Constructor(s) of that Class.

If you really *can't* convert it, then I'd suggest creating a Factory Class to "construct" instances of this Struct; that class then takes on the responsibility for properly initialising instances of the Struct.

Comment: My actual case is very close to `LimitedString` I have shown. In fact, currently I have a class for it. Having a class for relatively simple value type often included in expressions does not look to me as a good idea, so I attempted to move it to struct. A factory class looks like a good idea (thanks) but programmers would need to be aware of it – maybe not very practical... also when considering its use in expressions.

Comment: Anyway, good answer. I'll re-evaluate supposed structure usage to decide whether to keep it as `class` or move to `struct` with that defaults trick shown in question as option #2 (code changes were minimal and it works nicely). Thank you for the insight.

Comment: Good answer.  There have been many objects I have made over the years that fit most of the qualifications for a structure (small, primitive types, value semantics made sense in context), but I chose to change them to immutable classes and then overrode Equals simply because the 0's and null defaults were not a valid state that I wanted to exist.  Overriding equals and keeping them immutable gets you close to the same usage as value semantics.

Comment: How does using factory help? It doesn't prevent the user from creating the default value.

Comment: I think the biggest problem with accidently generating invalid structs is things like `FirstOrDefault() `

Answer (score 5):

First note: I agree this should probably be a class. For a struct, though:

Is it possible to change the design? In `LimitedString`'s case, it sounds like `0` is perfectly fine: a string with no characters. You can't enforce anything with a default constructor (like you suggested in #1) because [structs (in C#) cannot contain explicit parameterless constructors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288208%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

For #2, maybe it's simpler to change the meaning of the struct's state to establish a good by-design default without adding an extra flag or a special-case `0` condition:

```
private int _maxLengthMinusTen; // By default 0, making MaxLength 10.
public int MaxLength => _maxLengthMinusTen + 10;
```

A constructor would perform the conversion from an input `maxLength`, or you could provide a private setter to keep the `10` localized in the code.

Comment: `private int _maxLengthMinusTen;` That's evil, I like it!

Comment: good...   actually `MaxLength` limit disallowing `0` is in databases... `char`/`varchar`/`text`... of course, `0` can stay for `max` as in `varchar(max)`

Comment: @miroxlav Ah, didn't think about it being dependent on a more set in stone limit. I loosened the language a bit there.

Answer (score 1):

> How to implement some constrained .NET `struct`, where its state with default values (set by CLR to technical defaults, i.e. nulls, zeros, etc.) should be prohibited due to some design constraint?

You can't. As of 2022 and C# 10.0, there still is no way to prevent consuming code from having `default` struct values:

```
LimitedString[] values = new LimitedString[ 5 ];
MethodThatRequiresNonNullString( values[0].Value ); // <-- This will always fail at runtime, without _any_ compile-time warnings or errors.
```

*Q.E.D.*

<sub>Whereas if `LimitedString` were a `class` type, *and* if C# 8.0 nullable-reference-types were enabled, you'd get a compile-time warning that `LimitedString[] values` should be typed as `LimitedString?[]` and that the `values[0].Value` dereference is unsafe.</sub>.

However this does not necessarily mean that you should be using a `class` type for this: it just means you need to understand how you *can* implement `struct` types correctly and appropriately.

> For example in case of trivial `struct LimitedString`, properties are `String Value` and `int MaxLength`, where value of the `MaxLength` property must be at least `1`. Value `0` is not allowed by design.
>
> But when I initialize the structure, I have 0 there. How to force value `10` into defaults?

You appear to be thinking that it's okay to define classes and structs that can be instantiated *into an invalid state* and then set their properties *afterwards* until they're somehow "initialized". **This is not how classes nor structs should be designed**.

<sup>(I blame WinForms and WPF/XAML for so many .NET developers getting into this plainly *wrong* mindset, because WinForms and WPF/XAML basically require all component classes to have parameterless constructors and be post-hoc initialized).</sup>

Constructors exist to ensure that their newly created objects are in a *specific* valid state, this means having to [assert preconditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precondition)  about their parameter values (using `ArgumentException`). And in .NET, `struct` types should always be immutable (which necessarily means that their properties are strictly `get`-only: no `set` nor `init` properties!) so always write `readonly struct`-types, not `struct`-types.

With that in mind, let's review your first question again:

> But when I initialize the structure, I have 0 there. How to force value `10` into defaults?

You should make `maxLength` a constructor parameter, *not as a property you set after construction* - which means it can also validate the `String value`.

However because `maxLength` is not an *invariant* of your program it means your `LimitedString` becomes less useful (e.g. e.g. a method that accepts a `LimitedString limStr` parameter *has no useful compile-time guarantees* that the actual `limStr.Value.Length` is anything but non-zero, so it would have to check the ``limStr.Value.Length`itself at runtime which is hardly better than just passing a`String`value.  Instead the`MaxLength`value should be expressed as a _type-parameter_ of`LimitedString`, e.g.` LimitedString<MaxLength: 10>`, unfortunately C# does not support` int`type-parameters like C++ does - but you can hack it in other ways... <sub>(but that's another discussion...)</sub> - but I'll continue with my answer anyway, but I'll disregard the _invariance_ aspects of your`MaxLength` design.

> Throw exception in `static` parameterless constructor → force using only costructor(s) with parameters. Impractical, parameterless use is expected sometimes.

Again, you misunderstand the purpose of constructors (and are also seemingly getting confused by the type-level `static LimitedString()` "static constructor", which is actually completely irrelevant to your question, as your `struct LimitedString` won't have any `static` members).

You should have a parameterized constructor (accepting `String value, Int32 maxLength`) and your constructor **must** `throw new ArgumentException` to make precondition assertions about those parameter's arguments values. **That's the whole point of a constructor**, regardless of if it's a `struct` or a `class`'s constructor.

...However, because C#/.NET `struct` types *always* have a parameterless constructor that cannot be manually defined or removed (an unavoidable consequence of the low-level details of how `struct` types work: it's their `default` or "zero" value!) So in C#, whenever you're writing a method with a `struct`-type parameter or `struct`-typed property-setter you always need to be cognizant of the possibility that *that* input is `default`: and then act accordingly depending on your business/domain rules (i.e. "can a `default` or "uninitialized" value of this type ever be considered **valid** in my program?"). If not, then your program needs to reject it in appropriately: either by throwing an `ArgumentException`, returning `false` from a `Try...`-pattern method,  etc.

> Add helper private field `IsInitialized` and while it is `false`, assume default values, i.e. `MaxLength = 10`. Slightly higher complexity inside the struct.

You actually wouldn't need to add a whole new field to detect `default` struct state: assuming your constructor requires the `String value` argument to be non-`null` (in addition to checking the length) before storing it in `readonly String myStringValue;` then you *know* that if the struct is `default` then the `myStringValue` field will also be `null` (as `null == default(String)`) - so just checking if `this.myStringValue is null` is enough to tell you the struct is invalid. But you don't even have to do that: the as you said `MaxLength` must be `> 0` and because `default(Int32) == 0` you could always just check if `this.maxLengthValue == default(Int32)` to see if your struct is invalid.

> Slightly higher complexity inside the struct.

Unfortunately in the case of `struct` types, that "slightly higher complexity" **is absolutely necessary** because a `struct`'s member methods and properties can be invoked on `default` instances (whereas a `class` will never have its instance methods invoked when `this == null`), so all of your structs' externally visible (i.e. `public` and `internal` members) must self-validate `this` as a precondition.

> Is option #2 a legitimate way or does this violate some design principles?

On the contrary: Option #2 **is the only way** (and *Option #1* is either nonsensical or demonstrates a lack of understanding of OOP fundamentals and the purpose of constructors).

With that in mind, let's review the hard-and-fast rules for `struct` type design (especially since C# 7 made significant improvements to `struct` types with the addition of `readonly struct`, for example):

### TL;DR: aka Hard and fast rules:

- If your instance's data is mutable, [or exceeds ~32 bytes in aggregate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407691/why-is-16-byte-the-recommended-size-for-struct-in-c), then  then you should use a `class` instead of a `struct`.
- [Use `readonly struct LimitedString`, not `struct LimitedString`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/write-safe-efficient-code).
- Define your `struct LimitedString`'s state using only fields, not auto-properties...

  - ...and **never** read those fields directly!
  - Instead all *read* access to those fields should be indirectly done via wrapper getter-only properties, which all ensure `this != default(LimitedString)` before returning.
- Ensure all members and consumers of your `struct LimitedString` use *only* those self-validating wrapper properties.

### But why?

Because *any and all* `struct`-types *can always* possibly be `default`, it means that if struct-type's `default` state is invalid (and so should never be encountered during program operation) it means all public members of structs **must** be self-validating in some way or another.

I find the best approach is to always use `private readonly` fields and require all access to their data to by via an expression-bodied property that performs the state validation. This does mean that you cannot use auto-properties to avoid having to define both the field and property for the same logical member **grumble**.

Rather than using your `struct LimitedString` for my first example, let's review this contrived example `struct Foo` instead, which features more problem-areas:

```csharp
public struct Foo
{
    public Foo( Bar bar, Qux qux, Int32 neverZero, Int32 canBeZero )
    {
        if( neverZero == 0 ) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException( paramName: nameof(neverZero), actualValue: neverZero, message: "Cannot be zero." );

        this.Bar = bar ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bar));
        this.qux = qux ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(qux));
        this.NeverZero = neverZero;
        this.CanBeZero = canBeZero 
    }

    public Bar Bar { get; }
    private readonly Qux qux;
    public Int32 NeverZero { get; }
    public Int32 CanBeZero { get; }

    public SomethingElse Baz()
    {
        return this.Bar.Hmmm( this.qux ).LoremIpsum( 123 );
    }

    public CompletelyDifferent MyHovercraftIsFullOfEels()
    {
        return this.qux.IWillNotBuyThistTobaccanistItIsScratched();
    }
}
```

...you'll *need* this instead:

```csharp
public readonly struct Foo
{
    public Foo( Bar bar, Qux qux, Int32 neverZero, Int32 canBeZero )
    {
        if( neverZero == 0 ) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException( paramName: nameof(neverZero), actualValue: neverZero, message: "Cannot be zero." );
        
        this.bar_DoNotReadDirectlyExceptViaProperty = bar ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bar));
        this.qux_DoNotReadDirectlyExceptViaProperty = qux ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(qux));
        this.NeverZero = neverZero;
        this.CanBeZero = canBeZero 
    }

    private readonly Bar    bar_DoNotReadDirectlyExceptViaProperty;
    private readonly Qux    qux_DoNotReadDirectlyExceptViaProperty;
    private readonly Int32  neverZero_DoNotReadDirectlyExceptViaProperty;
    private readonly Int32? canBeZero_DoNotReadDirectlyExceptViaProperty;

    public  Bar Bar         => this.bar_DoNotReadDirectlyExceptViaProperty ?? throw new InvalidOperationException();
    private Qux Qux         => this.qux_DoNotReadDirectlyExceptViaProperty ?? throw new InvalidOperationException();
    public  Int32 NeverZero => this.neverZero_DoNotReadDirectlyExceptViaProperty != 0 ? this.neverZero_DoNotReadDirectlyExceptViaProperty : throw new InvalidOperationException();
    public  Int32 CanBeZero => this.canBeZero_DoNotReadDirectlyExceptViaProperty ?? throw new InvalidOperationException();

    public SomethingElse Baz()
    {
        return this.Bar.Hmmm( this.Qux ).LoremIpsum( 123 );
    }

    public CompletelyDifferent MyHovercraftIsFullOfEels()
    {
        return this.Qux.IWillNotBuyThistTobaccanistItIsScratched();
    }
}
```

- The main thing to observe here is that now *all* accesses of `struct Foo`'s state (i.e. its fields) from the `Baz` and `MyHovercraftIsFullOfEels` methods now go via the `Bar` and `Qux` properties instead of accessing the fields directly (which would cause a `NullReferenceException`, even when using C# 8.0 nullable-reference-types).
- The field name style `bar_DoNotReadDirectlyExceptViaProperty` is intentionally ugly: it mitigates the risk of *human-factors* (e.g. if the `struct Foo` code is ever modified in future by someone who is unfamiliar with the patterns in-use here) and ensures all access go through the self-validating wrapper properties: `Bar` and `Qux` respectively.

  - *Warning sign* naming is [a common technique](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml), e.g. `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` in ReactJS. I don't know if there's a formal name for the technique though.
  - Ideally C# would let us have property-scoped fields which would make this technique completely moot [but it doesn't](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/133). *Oh well*.

    - I suppose you could write a Roslyn code-analysis rule that enforces the requirement that all `readonly struct` fields are always read only via their matched self-validating properties.
- Observe how the self-validating property-getter throws `InvalidOperationException` [because that is the specific exception type you should use for this situation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.invalidoperationexception?view=net-6.0) (emphasis mine):

  > `InvalidOperationException`: The exception that is thrown **when a method call is invalid for the object's current state**.

  - I'm sure we're all familiar with the maxim that "property-getters should never throw exceptions", I'll remind everyone that it should really be rephrased as "property-getters on correctly constructed objects should never throw exceptions".

    - This is because it's the constructor's responsibility to ensure the object is in a valid state - **that's the entire point of constructors in the first place**: to make guarantees about the state of an object.
    - Therefore, if a `struct` value is not constructed correctly (e.g. `SomeStruct val = default(SomeStruct);`) then its property-getters *should* throw an exception, **because it's an exceptional circumstance** and you really do what the program to fail.
- The `Int32 canBeZero` value is stored in a `Nullable<Int32>` field (aka `Int32?` aka `int?`) because otherwise it is impossible to differentiate between `default(Int32)` and zero, while using `Nullable<Int32>` makes it possible to detect never-initialized fields that store `Int32` values - or any other value-type `T` where `default(T)` is meaningful in your application (e.g. `TimeSpan`).

  - However this isn't necessary for the `Int32 NeverZero` property because the domain-rules (which are implemented in the constructor) which specifically disallow zero means that `default(Int32)` is an invalid value, so there's no need to use `Nullable<Int32>` as the underlying field type.

### A better `struct LimitedString`

So having considered that, this is how I would design your `struct LimitedString`:

```csharp
public readonly struct LimitedString
{
    public LimitedString( String value, Int32 maxLength )
    {
        if( value is null ) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(value));
        if( maxLength < 1 ) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException( message: "Value must be positive and non-zero.", nameof(maxLength));
        if( value.Length > maxLength ) throw new ArgumentException( message: "Length {0} exceeds maxLength {1}.".Format( value.Length, maxLength ), nameof(value));

        this.value_doNotReadDirectly     = value;
        this.maxLength_doNotReadDirectly = maxLength;
    }
    
    private readonly String value_doNotReadDirectly;
    private readonly Int32  maxLength_doNotReadDirectly;

    public String Value => this.value_doNotReadDirectly ?? throw new InvalidOperationException( "This LimitedString is a default value and was not constructed correctly." );

    public Int32 MaxLength => this.maxLength_doNotReadDirectly > 1 ? this.this.maxLength_doNotReadDirectly : throw new InvalidOperationException( "This LimitedString is a default value and was not constructed correctly." );
}
```

While `struct LimitedString` now correctly handles both `default` and *constructed* states, it still needs other improvements made to it in order to make it suitable for production use, such as these listed below:

- With the above `public readonly struct LimitedString`, as-is, Visual Studio will instantly prompt you to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`.

  - [Implementing `GetHashCode` correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263400/what-is-the-best-algorithm-for-overriding-gethashcode) is very important for `struct` types and is an absolute requirement if you want to use it as a `TKey` type in a `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` or as `T` in `HashSet<T>`.
- You'll also want to override `ToString()` too, so you can pass `LimitedString` directly into `String.Format` args or `Console.Write`, as well as to get a better experience in the VS debugger.

  - This is trivial: just do `public override String ToString() => this.Value.ToString();`.
  - Also consider adding `[DebuggerDisplay]` too.
- Add an `implicit` conversion operator *to* `String`: because every valid `LimitedString` represents a valid `String`.

  - But don't add an `implicit` conversion *from* `String`: because **not** every non-null `String` is a valid `LimitedString`.

    - And also because `LimitedString` requires a `maxLength` parameter, which is not present in a normal `String` value, of course.
- Implement `IEquatable<LimitedString>` and maybe `IEquatable<String>` too.
- Add public methods and *forwarded `get`-only properties* to `LimitedString` that match the public API surface of `String` so that your `LimitedString` type can be a *drop-in replacement* for a `String` parameter or property in your existing code.

  - so add members like `public Int32 Length => this.Value.Length;` and `public String Trim() => this.Value.Trim();`.
  - This can be tedious though, and it is unfortunate that C# still cannot auto-generate those members for us.

### A real-world example: Refinement types.

I use `readonly struct`-types [as *refinement types*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refinement_type) in my projects, which is handy for when I want to express a static constraint over some business object.

For example, supposing I have `class User` with an *optional* `String? EmailAddress { get; }` property and I want to pass it around some in code that *requires* the `User` to have a valid e-mail address (not just *a non-null `String`* e-mail address value) then I'd solve this problem by defining `readonly struct UserWithValidEmailAddress : IReadOnlyUser` and then changing all member parameters and return-types in the code that requires e-mail addresses from `User` to `UserWithValidEmailAddress`, which means the compiler will give me a compile-time error if any code tries to pass a `User` (because that `User` object *could* have an invalid or absent e-mail address) without first validating it with a validating-factory method.

- I use `readonly struct` because that means it's essentially a *zero-cost abstraction*, which we don't get with `class`-types (as `class`-types always involve a GC allocation and subsequent collection) whereas `struct` types are "free" until/unless boxed.
- The use of `implicit` conversion and implementing the `IReadOnly...` interface means that `struct`-types lack of inheritance aren't problems either (and even if these refinement types *were* `class` types instead of `struct` types *inheritance would be the worst way to implement them*).

  - In all of my projects I always define `IReadOnly...` interfaces for all domain-types, so `class User` will have `IReadOnlyUser` which has only read-only versions of `User`'s instance properties in addition to all methods that don't cause any mutation.

    - Having `IReadOnly...` interfaces is also useful because C# still doesn't have C++-style `const`-correctness. **grumble**.

Unfortunately because `struct`-types *can always exist* in their `default` form, it's necessary for them to self-validate inside every public instance member, not just inside their parameterized constructor. And unfortunately, C# auto-properties (used for brevity) cannot self-validate, which makes them unsafe - so those have to be implemented as private fields with public get-only properties which throw `InvalidOperationException` if they detect they're in an invalid/`default` state (which is trivial: just ensure that reference-type fields are non-`null`, or if all fields are value-types, then use `System.Nullable<T>` for the first field and throw if that's `null` at runtime - or add a `bool` field that will always be `true` if any of the defined ctors are used).

So this is what my `UserWithValidEmailAddress` looks like:

```
public readonly struct UserWithValidEmailAddress : IReadOnlyUser
{
    public static Boolean TryCreate( User user, [NotNullWhen(true)] out UserWithValidEmailAddress? valid )
    {
        if( ValidateEmailAddress( user.EmailAddress ) )
        {
            valid = new ValidateEmailAddress( user, new MailAddress( user.EmailAddress ) );
            return true;
        } 
        valid = default;
        return false;
    }

    public static implicit operator User( UserWithValidEmailAddress self )
    {
        return self.User;
    }

    private UserWithValidEmailAddress( User user, MailAddress addr )
    {
        this.user_DoNotReadDirectlyExceptViaProperty = value ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(user));
        this.validatedMailAddress = addr ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(value));
    }

    private readonly User user_DoNotReadDirectlyExceptViaProperty;
    private readonly MailAddress validatedMailAddress;

    public User User => this.user_DoNotReadDirectlyExceptViaProperty ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("This is a default(UserWithValidEmailAddress).");

    public MailAddress ValidEmailAddress => this.validatedMailAddress ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("This is a default(UserWithValidEmailAddress).");

    public override String ToString() => this.User.ToString();

#region IReadOnlyUser
    // This code-block is generated by my own tooling, which helps with the tedium.
    // Because all of these members go through `UserWithValidEmailAddress.User` (which self-validates) instead of directly accessing the `user_DoNotReadDirectlyExceptViaProperty` field it means `default`-safety is guaranteed.

    public String   UserName    => this.User.UserName;
    public String   DisplayName => this.User.DisplayName;
    public DateTime Created     => this.User.Created;
    
    // etc

    // The IReadOnlyUser.EmailAddress property is implemented explicitly, instead of as a public member, because it's redundant: if a method is using `UserWithValidEmailAddress` then it should use the `MailAddress ValidEmailAddress` property instead.
    String IReadOnlyUser.EmailAddress => this.User.EmailAddress;

#endregion
}
```

While this looks tedious to write every time I want a refinement type, [I have a VS code-snippet that inserts the outline for me](https://gist.github.com/Jehoel/ef9fd596400de163be3671c768ab3757), as well as having other tooling to automatically generate the `#region IReadOnlyUser` part too.