# struct with nonsensical default value

Tags: c#, object-oriented, strings

In my system I frequently operate with airport codes (`"YYZ"`, `"LAX"`, `"SFO"`, etc.), they are always in the exact same format (3 letter, represented as uppercase).  The system typically deals with 25-50 of these (different) codes per API request, with over a thousand allocations total, they are passed around through many layers of our application, and are compared for equality quite often.

We started with just passing strings around, which worked fine for a bit but we quickly noticed lots of programming mistakes by passing in a wrong code somewhere the 3 digit code was expected.  We also ran into issues where we were supposed to do a case-insensitive comparison and instead did not, resulting in bugs.

From this, I decided to stop passing strings around and create an `Airport` class, which has a single constructor that takes and validates the airport code.

```
public sealed class Airport
{
    public Airport(string code)
    {
        if (code == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(code));
        }

        if (code.Length != 3 || !char.IsLetter(code[0]) 
        || !char.IsLetter(code[1]) || !char.IsLetter(code[2]))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(
                "Must be a 3 letter airport code.", 
                nameof(code));
        }

        Code = code.ToUpperInvariant();
    }

    public string Code { get; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Code;
    }

    private bool Equals(Airport other)
    {
        return string.Equals(Code, other.Code);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return obj is Airport airport && Equals(airport);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Code?.GetHashCode() ?? 0;
    }

    public static bool operator ==(Airport left, Airport right)
    {
        return Equals(left, right);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Airport left, Airport right)
    {
        return !Equals(left, right);
    }
}
```

This made our code much easier to understand and we simplified our equality checks, dictionary / set usages.  We now know that if our methods accept an `Airport` instance that it will behave the way we expect, it has simplified our method checks to a null reference check.

The thing I did notice, however, was the garbage collection was running much more often, which I tracked down to a lot of instances of `Airport` getting collected.

My solution to this was to convert the `class` into a `struct`.  Mostly it was just a keyword change, with the exception of `GetHashCode` and `ToString`:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return Code ?? string.Empty;
}

public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return Code?.GetHashCode() ?? 0;
}
```

To handle the case where `default(Airport)` is used.

My questions:

1. Was creating an `Airport` class or struct a good solution in general, or am I solving the wrong problem / solving it the wrong way by creating the type?  If it's not a good solution, what is a better solution?
2. How should my application handle instances where the `default(Airport)` is used?  A type of `default(Airport)` is nonsensical to my application, so I've been doing `if (airport == default(Airport) { throw ... }` in places where getting an instance of `Airport` (and its `Code` property) is critical to the operation.

Notes:
I reviewed the questions [C#/VB struct – how to avoid case with zero default values, which is considered invalid for given structure?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/318398/c-vb-struct-how-to-avoid-case-with-zero-default-values-which-is-considered-i), and [Use struct or not](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/342371/use-struct-or-not) before asking my question, however I think my questions are different enough to warrant its own post.

Comment: Does the garbage collection have a *material* impact on the way your application performs?  In other words, does it matter?

Comment: Anyway, yes, the class solution was a "good" one.  The way you know that is it solved your problem without creating any new ones.

Comment: One way you can solve the `default(Airport)` problem is by simply disallowing default instances.  You can do that by writing a parameterless constructor and throwing `InvalidOperationException` or `NotImplementedException` in it.

Comment: On a side note, instead of confirming that your initialization string is in fact 3 alpha characters, why not just compare it to the finite list of all airport codes (e.g., [github.com/datasets/airport-codes](https://github.com/datasets/airport-codes) or similar)?

Comment: Can you make up a three character code to represent the `default(Airport)`? Something semi obvious like "---"?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I like your parameterless constructor solution.  As for the actual performance impact, I need to do more testing, but from profiling it looks to be the GC is running at the end of every API call, so this was my first candidate for fixing performance in my app.  I wanted to know the impacts of converting to a struct before blindly doing it.

Comment: structs are meant to be used in "Value-Type" contexts.  Your 3-character airport code should behave like a value type, IMO.

Comment: I'm willing to bet several beers that this is not the root of a performance problem. A normal laptop can allocate in the order 10M objects/seconds.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update:** I rewrote my answer to address some incorrect assumptions about C# structs, as well as the OP informing us in comments that interned strings are being used.

---

If you can control the data coming in to your system, use a class as you posted in your question. If someone runs `default(Airport)` they will get a `null` value back. Be sure to write your private `Equals` method to return false whenever comparing null Airport objects, and then let the `NullReferenceException`'s fly elsewhere in the code.

However, if you are taking data into the system from sources you don't control, you don't necessary want to crash the whole thread. In this case a struct is ideal for the simple fact `default(Airport)` will give you something other than a `null` pointer. Make up an obvious value to represent "no value" or the "default value" so you have something to print on screen or in a log file (like "---" for instance). In fact, I would just keep the `code` private and not expose a `Code` property at all — just focus on behavior here.

```
public struct Airport
{
    private string code;

    public Airport(string code)
    {
        // Check `code` for validity, throw exceptions if not valid

        this.code = code;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return code ?? (code = "---");
    }

    // int GetHashcode()

    // bool Equals(...)

    // bool operator ==(...)

    // bool operator !=(...)

    private bool Equals(Airport other)
    {
        if (other == null)
            // Even if this method is private, guard against null pointers
            return false;

        if (ToString() == "---" || other.ToString() == "---")
            // "Default" values should never match anything, even themselves
            return false;

        // Do a case insensitive comparison to enforce logic that airport
        // codes are not case sensitive
        return string.Equals(
            ToString(),
            other.ToString(),
            StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
    }
}
```

Worse case scenario converting `default(Airport)` to a string prints out `"---"` and returns false when compared to other valid Airport codes. Any "default" airport code matches nothing, including other default airport codes.

Yes, structs are meant to be values allocated on the stack, and any pointers to heap memory basically negate the performance advantages of structs, but in this case the default value of a struct has meaning and provides some additional bullet resistance to the rest of the application.

I would bend the rules a little here, because of that.

---

**Original Answer** (with some factual errors)

If you can control the data coming in to your system, I would do as Robert Harvey suggested in the comments: Create a parameterless constructor and throw an exception when it is called. This prevents invalid data from entering the system via `default(Airport)`.

```
public Airport()
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException("...");
}
```

However, if you are taking data into the system from sources you don't control, you don't necessary want to crash the whole thread. In this case you can create an airport code that is invalid, but make it seem like an obvious error. This would involve creating a parameterless constructor and setting the `Code` to something like "---":

```
public Airport()
{
    Code = "---";
}
```

Since you are using a `string` as the Code, there is no point in using a struct. The struct gets allocated on the stack, only to have the `Code` allocated as a pointer to a string in heap memory, so no difference here between class and struct.

If you changed the airport code to a 3 item array of char's then a struct would be fully allocated on the stack. Even then the volume of data isn't that big to make a difference.

Comment: If my application were using interned strings for the `Code` property, would that change your justification regarding your point of the string being in heap memory?

Comment: @Matthew: Is using a class giving you a performance problem? If not, then flip a coin to decide which to use.

Comment: @Matthew: Really the important thing is you centralized the troublesome logic of normalizing the codes and comparisons. After that "class versus struct" is just an academic discussion, until you measure a big enough impact in performance to justify the extra developer time to have an academic discussion.

Comment: That's true, I don't mind having an academic discussion from time to time if it helps me create better informed solutions in the future.

Comment: @Matthew: Yup, you are absolutely right. They say "talk is cheap." It's certainly cheaper than not talking and building something poorly. :)

Comment: The parameterless constructor will not work as described. default(Airport) will not call the parameterless constructor in a struct. It is not possible to prevent the initialization of a struct with the default value, which is always just the zero'ed memory.

Comment: @TheFogger: true. I'll have to update my answer tomorrow.

Comment: Also, the tricks about where things get allocated are unnecessary if you use my answer.

Comment: @TheFogger: I ended up rewriting my answer. Same basic advice (throw exceptions if you control the input, intelligent default if taking in a data import) but the technical solutions differ. I kept my original answer at the bottom of the post for some context.

Answer (score 13):

**Use the [Flyweight pattern](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern)**

Since Airport is, correctly, immutable, there is no need to create more than one instance of any particular one, say, SFO.  Use a Hashtable or similar (note, I'm a Java guy, not C# so exact details might vary), to cache Airports when they get created.  Before creating a new one, check in the Hashtable.  You are never freeing up Airports, so GC has no need to free them.

One additional minor advantage (at least in Java, not sure about C#) is that you don't need to write an `equals()` method, a simple `==` will do.  Same for `hashcode()`.

Comment: Excellent usage of the flyweight pattern.

Comment: Assuming OP keeps using a struct and not a class, isn't _string interning_ already handling the reusable string values? The structs already live on the stack, the strings are alreadybeing reused so as to avoid duplicate values in memory. What additional benefit would be gained from the flyweight pattern?

Comment: Something to watch out for. If an airport is added or removed you'll want to build in a way to refresh this static list without restarting the application or redeploying it. Airports aren't added or removed often, but business owners tend to get a little upset when a simple change becomes this complicated. "Can't I just add it someplace?! Why do we have to schedule a release/application restart and inconvenience our customers?" But I was also thinking of using some sort of static cache at first too.

Comment: @Flater Reasonable point.   I'd say less need for junior programmers to reason about stack vs. heap.  Plus see my addition - no need to write equals().

Comment: @Greg Burghardt If the `getAirportOrCreate()` code is properly synchronized, there's no _technical_ reason you can't create new Airports as needed during runtime.  There may be business reasons.

Answer (score 3):

I’m not a particularly advanced programmer, but wouldn’t this be a perfect use for an Enum?

There are different ways to construct enum classes from lists or strings. Here’s one I’ve seen in the past, not sure if it’s the best way though.

https://blog.kloud.com.au/2016/06/17/converting-webconfig-values-into-enum-or-list/

Comment: When there are potentially thousands of different values (as is the case with airport codes), an enum just isn't practical.

Comment: Yes, but the link I posted is how to load strings as enums. Here's another link to load a lookup table as an enum. It might be a bit of work, but would take advantage of the power of enums.
https://exceptionnotfound.net/using-t4-templates-to-generate-enums-from-database-lookup-tables/

Comment: Or a list of valid codes could be loaded from a database or file.  Then an airport code is just checked to be among that list.  This is what you typically do when you no longer want to hardcode the values and/or the list becomes to long to manage.

Comment: @BenCottrell that is precisely what code gen and T4 templates are for.

Answer (score 3):

One of the reasons you're seeing more GC activity is because you're creating a second string now -- the `.ToUpperInvariant()` version of the original string. The original string is eligible for GC right after the constructor runs and the second one is eligible at the same time as the `Airport` object is. You might be able to minimize it in a different fashion (note the third parameter to `string.Equals()`):

```
public sealed class Airport : IEquatable<Airport>
{
    public Airport(string code)
    {
        if (code == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(code));
        }

        if (code.Length != 3 || !char.IsLetter(code[0])
                             || !char.IsLetter(code[1]) || !char.IsLetter(code[2]))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(
                "Must be a 3 letter airport code.",
                nameof(code));
        }

        Code = code;
    }

    public string Code { get; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Code; // TODO: Upper-case it here if you really need to for display.
    }

    public bool Equals(Airport other)
    {
        return string.Equals(Code, other?.Code, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return obj is Airport airport && Equals(airport);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Code.GetHashCode();
    }

    public static bool operator ==(Airport left, Airport right)
    {
        return Equals(left, right);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Airport left, Airport right)
    {
        return !Equals(left, right);
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this yield different hash codes for equal (but differently capitalized) Airports?

Comment: Yeah, I would imagine so. Dangit.

Comment: This is a very good point, never thought of it, I'll look at making these changes.

Comment: In regards to `GetHashCode`, should just use `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.GetHashCode(Code)` or similar